# dictionaries - check if value has key

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, dictionary

The idea is to verify if a value of a dict has a certain key. How to achieve that? I tried has_key() option but it's not working and it's deprecated in Python3

```
>>> a = {'q':1, 'w':2, 'e':3}
>>> for keys in a.keys():
...     print keys
... 
q
e
w
>>> for values in a.values():
...     print values
... 
1
3
2
>>> for values in a.values():
...     if values.has_key('q'):
...         print values
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

I simply need to print those values, which has a certain key.

Comment: I'm not getting what you want to do: `values` variables (you'd rather call that `value`by the way) are integers, so this error is pretty clear… In you want to check whether `a` has a key `'q'`, just use `'q' in a`

Comment: @martineau I don't see how you concluded that this is python3. Lookin at non-function print usages, this probably is not python3.

Comment: @martineau I see that, but again, looking at print usages, I think you should ask for a clarification before adding that tag.

Comment: @Lafexlos: I did by also marking the question as unclear. The confusion is part of the reason there's so many answers as everyone tries to _guess_ what the OP is really asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
a = {'q':1, 'w':2, 'e':3}
target = 'q'

for k,v in a.items():
    if k == target:
        print(v)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. Thank you!

Comment: This is an inefficient way to access a dictionary. All you need is `if target in a: print a[target]`

Comment: If you have multiple targets just make a list of them `targets = ['q','z',...]` then change in the code `if k in targets:`

Comment: @PM2Ring, I just simplified the question because I need this for the template in Django. There is no way to use a[target] in Django templates. Thanks

Comment: @JohnyJho: Questions _should_ be simplified as much as possible, but no further. :) If you simplify the question to the point where the answers do not apply to your real code, then you need to fix the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'in'

```
for values in a:
    if values in a:
        print(values)
```

Comment: for values in a, if values in a........ O_O??

Comment: This will simply print all of the **keys** of the dictionary `a`.